# How to set up the cookie with browser sync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, browser-sync, webapi2

I am using browser sync and a web api C# 2.0, when I call a method to login it returns in the response headers set-cookie, but the method does not set cookie in the browser.

```
browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    cors: true,
    port: 6543,
    server: {
        baseDir: config.dir.src,
        routes: {
            "/bower_components": "bower_components"
        },
        middleware: [function(req, res, next) {
            next();
        }]
    }
});
```

**Edit**

Login returns cookie:
[image]

Cookie browser:
[image]

Comment: is request being made cross origin .. different port , subdomain or domain?

Comment: no, i am on localhost

Comment: and webapi is exact same as page? Tell us more about login request and how you determine cookie not set

Comment: Whenever I try to login, it works fine, and the cookie is sent back from the server. However, the next call to the api returns me an unauthorized error. When I was trying to find out what was going on, I noticed that the cookies are not set in my browser storage. I tried the same using postman and it worked fine aswell.

Comment: doubt it has anything to do with browserSync but does it work if you disable browserSync?

Comment: using iis it works

Comment: that's not very informative  .... no difference in page origin?

Comment: Even when I manually set the cookie, I still getting the same unauthorized response... there is no difference. Seems as if the get request i'm sending can't read the cookie from my browser.

Comment: That response has CORS headers which makes me think request is not to same origin as page is on and you would need to set `withCredentials` in request